# Problema con tabla en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema al generar una tabla por JavaScript, en el código que os muestro a continuación las filas se generan a la derecha en vez de seguir por abajo para seguir la columna, la primera columna y la primera fila tienen que tener <'th'> como requisito y las demás celdas <'td'>.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible desarollar la tabla así por JavaScript?.

```js
function genera_tabla() {
 
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    
    var hilera = document.createElement("th");
 
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

      var celda = document.createElement("td");
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("fila "+i+", columna "+j + "\n");
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
  }
 
  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);

  body.appendChild(tabla);
 
  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<html>
 
<input type="button" value="Genera una tabla" onclick="genera_tabla()">
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error: `var hilera = document.createElement("tr");`en lugar de `var hilera = document.createElement("th");`

Pata crear las celdas `th`he utilizado

```js
let elmt = (j == 0 || i == 0) ? "th" : "td";
var celda = document.createElement(elmt);
```

```js
function genera_tabla() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      let elmt = (j == 0 || i == 0) ? "th" : "td";
      var celda = document.createElement(elmt);
      var textoCelda = "fila " + i + ", columna " + j + "\n";
      celda.textContent = textoCelda;
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
  }

  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);

  body.appendChild(tabla);

  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<html>
 
<input type="button" value="Genera una tabla" onclick="genera_tabla()">
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un th donde debe ir un tr, solo con ese cambio ya queda en formato de tabla.

Ten presente que los th son celdas para titulos y los td son celdas para contenido, en otras palabras estas metiendo una celda en otra celda y no una celda en una fila

La fila con los titulos (th) no debe hacer parte del for que llena la tabla